# Start replSet automatically

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, ubuntu-20.04

I am pretty new to installing MongoDB on Server. It was for a MERN stack project. And in order to use a library [Pusher](https://pusher.com/). I need to convert the Stand Alone Server to Replication set.

So I used the script `sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --replSet rs1 --bind_ip localhost,<my server ip>` and the terminal will start logging. And then I can use another terminal to access the MongoDB database. But the problem is the moment I close the logging terminal (where I used the `--replSet` script) I will be prevented from accessing the MongoDB database.

[image: code preview]

So is there any way to automatically execute the `--replSet` script as soon as the server starts and keep it running?

Comment: Install mongoDB as a service.

Comment: I am using a server running Ubuntu 20 LTS. Followed instructions from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04). Can you recommend a link that gives instruction on installing mongodb as service?

Comment: Maybe the obvious one? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/